# Cahn–Ingold–Prelog priority of carboxylic group versus ortho carboxylic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry

Should the C=C double bond below be labelled as (*E*) or (*Z*)?

[image: (2​E)-3-bromo-3-iodo-2-(trihydroxymethyl)prop-2-enoic acid]

Answer (score 5):

When using the Cahn–Ingold–Prelog (CIP) priority system and the ‘Sequence Rules’, double bonds are split into two bonds and the doubly bonded atoms are duplicated.

Thus

[image]

is treated as

[image]

where (O) and (C) are duplicate representations of the atoms at the other end of the double bond;

whereas

[image]

is treated as

[image]

Therefore, the name of the structure that is given in the question is (2​*E*)-3-bromo-3-iodo-2-(trihydroxymethyl)prop-2-enoic acid.

[image: (2E)-3-bromo-3-iodo-2-(trihydroxymethyl)prop-2-enoic acid]

Comment: You should note that in the first step (turning $\ce{C(=O)OH}$ into $\ce{C(-O-(C))(-(O))(-O)}$ and comparing that to $\ce{C(-O)(-O)(-O)}$ the two are still equivalent. You need to step down one step further to see that the highest priority O of the carboxyl group is bonded to a dummy C whose priority is higher than that of the true H on the carboxylic hydrate. That might help clear remaining confusion.

Answer (score -2):

The compound doesn't exist as drawn, it would dehydrate to the symmetric diacid.  That being said, I'd guess Z as the extra hydrogen atoms on the imaginery acid hydrate increase it's priority over the acid.

Comment: no changed my mind - according to this The acid is higer priority.  looks like your old professor was right.. The old dog.  http://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/Chemistry/Rizzo/chem220a/priority.pdf

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help].

Comment: @WooTangClan You should edit your answer instead of putting edits in the comments.

Comment: Whether or not the orthoacid exists is irrelevant!

Answer (score -3):

Simple. The rule is that at the tie..(carbon)...there are three ligands of equivalent priority...however, since their not both acids, **the rule is that sp2 hybridization beats sp3**.

Also, you'll never isolate that geminal (or triplet) alcohol, someone called it an acid hydrate..(even hydrates of aldehydes are difficult to isolate). Only as an orthoester can such structures be isolated.